# Python List Files as if using ls

Tags: python

I want to know if there is a way to list all files in a directory as if using the ls command, with the formatted output (I am on windows, so I can't use the ls command).

Comment: What's wrong with `os.listdir` function?

Comment: If you're trying to replicate `ls -l`, then as well as `os.listdir` you may be interested in some other `os` module functions listed in the [15.1.4. Files and Directories](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#files-and-directories) chapter of the Python docs. Eg, `os.access` and `os.stat`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Nothing, I just want to format the output of os.listdir as if I was using ls, but if all comes down to it I will just get a third party application.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want ls,cat,Ssh,git... Try "cmder" for Windows :)

http://bliker.github.io/cmder